Flutterwave IP Whitelisting Issue: "This request cannot be processed" despite Whitelisting IPv4 Address
I'm currently integrating Flutterwave for transactions, but I'm facing an issue when attempting a transfer. The response I receive is:
{
'status': 'error',
'message': 'This request cannot be processed. Please contact your account administrator',
'data': None
}
Additionally, I'm receiving an email notification stating that my IP address is not whitelisted in my Flutterwave account.
Here are the steps I've followed so far:

I added my IPv4 address to the IP whitelisting section in the Flutterwave dashboard.
However, I still encounter the same error during transactions.
In some tutorials and guides, I've seen that Flutterwave prompts for an OTP when adding an IP address for whitelisting, but in my case, I'm not being prompted for OTP.

My questions
1)Why am I still getting the "IP not whitelisted" issue even though I've added my IPv4 address to the Flutterwave IP whitelisting?
2)Shouldn't I be prompted for an OTP when adding an IP address for whitelisting, or has this process changed?
3)Is there something I'm missing or an additional step required to ensure my IP address is correctly recognized?
What I tried:
Whitelisting my IPv4 address: I added my public IPv4 address to the Flutterwave dashboard under the IP whitelisting section.
Rechecked the whitelisted IP: I double-checked to make sure the correct IP address was entered.
Testing the transaction: After whitelisting the IP, I attempted a transaction again, expecting it to be processed without any issues.
Verified documentation: I reviewed several tutorials and guides, and most indicate that an OTP should be sent when adding a new IP for whitelisting, but I was never prompted for an OTP.

What I expected:
I expected the transfer transaction to go through successfully after whitelisting the IP address. I also anticipated receiving an OTP when adding the IP address, as mentioned in the documentation and tutorials, but I didn’t get one.

Unfortunately, this information isn’t included in the documentation. In test mode, OTP verification isn’t actually used. You can set the IP address to 0.0.0.0 to allow all IPs in test mode.
